# How to get input from an Xbox One controller on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, xbox-one

I'm building a robot, and I'm using my Raspberry Pi to control it. I'd like to use an Xbox One controller for an input device.

First, is it possible? Second, which programming language should I use?

Comment: I used C. SDL has great joystick and game controller support.

Answer (score 0):

First off, yes it is very possible. To do it, you can buy a radio reciever (compatible with the raspberry pi) and set it to the frequency the x-box controller is transmitting at. Second, it would be easiest to use python2.7 or python3 because of all the third party packages you can use! Let me know if I helped!!